# How can I export a email template and pass props with react-email-editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nodemailer

I have learned how to embed the `Unlayer` template creator inside my App.

How can I export this into a `HTML` file so I can use it with `nodemailer`?

```
//where do I export this to?? How to handle this export?
 exportHtml = () => {
    this.editor.exportHtml(data => {
      const { design, html } = data
      console.log('exportHtml', html)
    })
  }
```

And I see that in the end it seems that I cannot treat this template as a `Component`, so how do devs use these templates to inject dynamic data?

this is API.

Please note on the imports that I am using `react-html-email` so far, as I have no idea how to use the template created with `eact-email-editor` with my code, as there is nothing nowhere explaining how to do this.

```
import axios from "axios"
import MyEmail from '../../views/Registration'
import { renderEmail } from 'react-html-email'

export const sendContactMail = async (recipientMail, name) => {
    const messageHtml =  renderEmail(<MyEmail />); // HTML code
    const data = {
        recipientMail,
        name,
        messageHtml
    }

    try {
        const res = await axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "/api/contact",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            data
        })
        return res

    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
}
```

and this is the code that ships my emails with `nodemailer`

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer"

const YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS = process.env.MAILER_MY_EMAIL;

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      type: "OAuth2",  
      user: YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
      serviceClient: process.env.MAILER_CLIENT_ID,
      privateKey: process.env.MAILER_PRIVATE_KEY
  }});

export default async (req, res) => {
    const { name, recipientMail, messageHtml } = req.body
    const mailerRes = await mailer({  name, recipientMail, messageHtml })
    res.send(mailerRes)
}

const mailer = ({  name,  recipientMail, messageHtml }) => {
    const message = {
        from: YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        to: `${recipientMail}`,
        subject: `New message from ${YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS}`,
        replyTo: YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        html: messageHtml
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        transporter.sendMail(message, (error, info) =>
            error ? reject(error) : resolve(info)
        )
    })
}
```

I am new to this part of the job, of dealing with templates, so sorry for my sense of lostness here. I am trying to undestand how does `react-email-editor` do me any good regarding the use with `nodemailer` and how to pass dynamic data with it. If I cannot do any of these things, I really will not undertand what this tool is for, as templates like this could be done on any of these websites that create static stuff.

Thanks in advance for anyone who comes to shed some light over here =D